# How to manipulate static variables of Native Android app using Frida?

Tags: android, native, reverse-engineering, instrumentation, frida

In order to practise Frida, I made a simple Unity app and dumped the apk via Il2cppInspector to get all the offsets.
So far I managed to intercept function, tamper its arguments and return value, I can also get and set the value of non-static fields (instance variables) by adding field's offset to instance of the class.

*Dumped file contains symbols and offsets:*

```
public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour // TypeDefIndex: 2195
{
    // Fields
    public static int a; // 0x00
    public static int b; // 0x04
    public int aa; // 0x10
    public int bb; // 0x14

    // Constructors
    public GameManager(); // 0x00666D88-0x00666E00
    static GameManager(); // 0x00666E00-0x00666E00

    // Methods
    private void Start(); // 0x006663F4-0x00666470
    public void ShowNonStatic(); // 0x006668B0-0x006668B8
    public void ShowNonStaticByGet(); // 0x00666944-0x006669C0
    public int GetNonStaticVal(int val); // 0x006668B8-0x00666944
    public void ShowStatic(); // 0x006669C8-0x00666AC0
    public void ShowStaticByGet(); // 0x00666B5C-0x00666CD4
    public int GetStaticVal(int val); // 0x00666CD4-0x00666D88
}
```

I can easily control **aa** and **bb** value with a *simple Frida's script:*

```
Module.ensureInitialized('libil2cpp.so');
const il2cpp = Module.findBaseAddress('libil2cpp.so');

Interceptor.attach(il2cpp.add('0x006668B0'), { // offset of ShowNonStatic()
    onEnter: function (args) {
        console.log('ShowNonStatic is called!');
        this.instance = args[0]; // args[0] is the ptr to instance of class GameManager
        var aa = this.instance.add('0x10'); // instance + offset of int aa
        var bb = this.instance.add('0x14'); // instance + offset of int bb
        // get value
        console.log('Value of aa is: ', aa.readInt());
        console.log('Value of bb is: ', bb.readInt());
        // set value
        console.log('aa is changed to: ', aa.writeInt(999)); // set aa = 999
        console.log('bb is changed to: ', bb.writeInt(000)); // set bb = 000
    }
})
```

But AFAIK, static variables are not part of the class instance so I can't use the implement above to change nor read the value of **a**, **b**. After some research, I found out that static variables are located in the data segment, so I opened libil2cpp.so with IDA and looked through the .bss and .data segment. But I still ended up hitting the wall since finding offsets inside a shared library is not a trivial task and I'm not familiar with IDA Pro either.

So how to access and manipulate the static fields like I did with non-static ones (calculate offset)? And is there any way to do it only using Frida?

Comment: take a look @ https://github.com/iddoeldor/mplus

Comment: well, I have tried to use Mplus for sevaral time before, both in Windows and Mac but I wasn't able to get it to work.
Your project is awesome, I wonder if it can support Il2cpp or just only for Mono? Cause I always get the same error when using it with Il2cpp based app, should I issue that error on Github or patse it on here?

Comment: Well.. i didn't look at il2cpp, so paste it here